# How do I modify a function so it loops through a file until the end in R?

Tags: r, function, loops, large-files

Quick Background: I have huge sets of data in CSV files. 183million rows by 8 columns. In the first column of each CSV file are some unique IDs, of which each repeats for a couple of rows.
**I'm trying to create a list of all unique ID's in one file.**
I had major memory issues trying to work with these files so a wrote a function using dplyr and data.table that outputs csv containing all unique ID's from one file.

```
findID_dplyr <- function(filename,iterations){
  ##############FUNCTION REQUIERES LIBRARIES: dplyr, data.table###############
  file.create("UserID_dplyr.csv")
  
  ID0 <- fread(filename, header = TRUE, nrows = 0, skip = 0, select = 1)
  write.table(ID0, file = "UserID_dplyr.csv", append = TRUE, quote = FALSE, col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, sep=",")
  
  for (i in 0:iterations){
    df <- fread(filename, header = TRUE, nrows = 100000, skip = i*100000, select = 1)
    
    df <- df %>%
            distinct(.keep_all = TRUE)
    
    write.table(df, file = "UserID_dplyr.csv", append = TRUE, quote = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, row.names = FALSE, sep=",")
    if(iterations!=0){
      percent <- 100/iterations*i
      print(paste(percent,"% completed..."))
    }

  }
  toclean  <- fread("UserID_dplyr.csv", header = TRUE)
  toclean <- toclean %>%
    distinct(.keep_all = TRUE)
  write.table(toclean, file = "UserID_dplyr.csv", sep = ",", col.names = TRUE, row.names = FALSE)
}
```

I used the iterations variable to test the code with small chunks and it seems to work. **I am now unsure how to modify the loop so it simply works through the entire file to the last line**. The files vary in the amount of row numbers so it would have to be a catch all solution.

(Side Note: If you have any comments on computational effiency, feel free to tell me, this is my first rodeo with a huge amount of data :D )

I'm guessing I'd have to use a while loop but I can't figure out what condition would then break the loop. I couldn't find a fitting code example online.

Comment: Consider using `duckdb`  and/or `arrow` packages for such data management. `duckdb` shall be enough and easy to go forward :). You can easily import the csv datasets to database and run SQL queries on it.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I will definitely look into that! If I import CSV datasets to the database, can I run SQL queries without loading the entire thing into memory?

Comment: Yes, you can, see example in answer.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple interface to `duckdb:`

```r
library(duckdb)
#> Loading required package: DBI

con = dbConnect(duckdb::duckdb(), dbdir="my-db.duckdb", read_only=FALSE)

d <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hypertidy/gdalwebsrv/master/inst/bundle/gdalwebsrv.csv")
dbWriteTable(con, "my_data", d)

a <- dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT provider, name FROM my_data WHERE name LIKE 'AIRS L2 Temperature%'")

a
#>   provider                                     name
#> 1     gibs   AIRS L2 Temperature 500hPa Day tileset
#> 2     gibs AIRS L2 Temperature 500hPa Night tileset
#> 3     gibs   AIRS L2 Temperature 700hPa Day tileset
#> 4     gibs AIRS L2 Temperature 700hPa Night tileset
#> 5     gibs   AIRS L2 Temperature 850hPa Day tileset
#> 6     gibs AIRS L2 Temperature 850hPa Night tileset
```

<sup>Created on 2022-11-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You can read your `csv` files sequentially and store the data in db, just run it with `dbAppendTable()` or `dbWriteTable(..., append = TRUE)`

Then you can run any cleaning or computation of data and store the values in db as well. https://duckdb.org/docs/api/r for reference.